# Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 in redux with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

So I have an async thunk function in redux:

```
export const fetchItem = createAsyncThunk('item/fetchItem', async (id: number) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())

    return res        
})
```

And here is my fetch function in react, it fetches the item by the html id of the event target (an  tag):

```
const handleFetch = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
        useAppDispatch(fetchItem(e.target.id))   
    }
```

The error is in the fetchItem and it says: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. I even tried just using:

```
useAppDispatch(fetchItem(1))
```

And got the same error.

useAppDispatch looks like this:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch} from "./redux/store";

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector()

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

Comment: What does `useAppDispatch` look like?

Comment: Just updated the question, you can see it now

Comment: `useAppDispatch` takes 0 arguments, but you pass 1. Also, it's a hook, but you are using it inside a function

Comment: Looking at other uses of this pattern, you're meant to have something like `const dispatch = useAppDispatch()` and then use `dispatch(fetchItem(whatever))`

Comment: So I can add for example 'params: any' to the parameter?

Comment: @IsaSeferović typescript is trying to help you, but you want to blame it. The problem is not related to typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `useAppDispatch` is a hook and can be used only directly inside component's body
2. `useAppDispatch` takes 0 arguments, but you pass 1
3. `useAppDispatch` returns a `dispatch` function that you wanted to use

```
// inside your component
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
const handleFetch = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
  dispatch(fetchItem(e.target.id))   
}
```